# Rails 3 : how to add css to jquery for autocomplete search

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got my jquery script :

```
<script>
$("#query").typeahead({
name: "pfile",
remote: "/pfiles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
});
</script>
```

typeahead style is declared above :

```
<head>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "typeahead" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-     ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

which is rendered in my (head) html section :

```
<link href="/assets/typeahead.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However my autocompletion has nothing nice and fancy. That works... but without CSS.
any ideas ? :)

Comment: Check your network tab in Chrome or Firefox/firebug to see any broken links for your css files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply =)       
http://localhost:3000/assets/typeahead.css?body=1 takes me to the proper CSS file, that's working fine..

Comment: Not sure anyone can help you without seeing the demo :/

Comment: typeahead css tag wasn't accordingly named in the stylesheet.. I renamed it .typeahead instead of .twitter something. that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

typeahead.css tags were not named accordingly in the stylesheet.. I renamed it

```
.typeahead
```

instead of

```
.twitter-ui
```

that worked !

This example helped me out a lot (inspecting elements, ...) :

http://www.arungudelli.com/jquery/simple-jquery-autocomplete-search-tutorial/

I spent a lot of time on that , I hope my post would save people some time =)